# Monotone Audio Converter (Python)

Tags: python, audio

A project I am working on requires audio to be standardized to a certain pitch. Is there any way (using Python) to generate "robotic" audio?

Ex. Input: Audio of a person talking, Output: Completely monotone soundtrack of the person speaking

So far, I've experimented with extracting pitches and pitch-shifting clips (which have not been successful).

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how to solve this using python libraries but using the `subprocess` module you can call external command line programs like ffmpeg and it's [loudnorm](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#loudnorm) filter.

This would look something like the following:

```
import subprocess as sp
fname = example.mp3
ffmpeg_path = ./ffmpeg

pipe = sp.Popen([ FFMPEG_BIN, '-i', 'fname-af' 'loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11'], stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: Cool! I already use ffmpeg for my other projects, so this is convenient.

Comment: I tried "ffmpeg -i audio.wav -filter:a loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11 test.wav", and the audio is the same. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called **ring modulation**.  Ring modulation is a signal processing technique that is commonly used to turn the sound of a normal, inflictive voice into a monotonous voice.  It was famously used to make the voice actor playing Dr. Dalek in *Dr. Who* sound robotic.

It is a very difficult technique requiring some hefty math and cannot easily be explained through a simple forum. I would recommend an adaption of [github/nrlakin/robot_voice](https://github.com/nrlakin/robot_voice) to your specific needs.  This particular repository contains a few Python programs that can take a .wav file as input, apply ring modulation, and output a .wav file of the monotonous voice.

Comment: Thanks! Ring modulation came up in few of my search results, but I wasn't quite sure what it was.

Comment: @Kento Nishi let me know how ring modulation turns out for you. If it works, you should accept the answer.

Comment: OK! I still haven't implemented it yet.